# Explicit Semantic Analysis

Tags: text, similarity, text-mining

I came across this term called 'Explicit Semantic Analysis ' which uses Wikipedia as a reference and finds the similarity in documents and categorizes them into classes (correct me if i am wrong).

The link i came across is [here](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~gabr/resources/code/esa/esa.html)

I wanted to learn more about it. Please help me out with it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This explicit semantic analysis works on similar lines as [semantic similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity) . I got hold of this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity) which provides a clear example of ESA

Comment: It's a bit redundant to have two links to the exact same page.