# difference between Latent and Explicit Semantic Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I'm trying to analyse the paper ''[Computing Semantic Relatedness
using Wikipedia-based Explicit Semantic
Analysis](http://ijcai.org/papers07/Papers/IJCAI07-259.pdf)''.

One component of the system described therein that I'm currently grappling with is the difference between Latent and Explicit Semantic Analysis.

I've been writing up a document to encapsulate my understanding but it's somewhat, "cobbled together", from sources which I don't 100% understand, so I'd like to know if what I've come up with is accurate, here it is:

```
When implementing a process like singular value decomposition (SVD) or Markov
chain Monte Carlo machines, a corpus of documents can be partitioned on the
basis of inherent characteristics and assigned to categories by applying different

weights to the features that constitute each singular data index. In this highdimensional
space it is often difficult to determine the combination of factors
leading to an outcome or result, the variables of interest are “hidden” or latent.
By defining a set of humanly intelligible categories, i.e. Wikipedia article
pages as a basis for comparison [Gabrilovich et al. 2007] have devised a system
whereby the criteria used to distinguish a datum are readily comprehensible,
from the text we note that “semantic analysis is explicit in the sense that we
manipulate manifest concepts grounded in human cognition, rather than ‘latent
concepts’ used by Latent Semantic Analysis”.
With that we have now established Explicit Semantic Analysis in opposition
to Latent Semantic Analysis.
```

is that accurate?

Info on this topic is somewhat sparse. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707624/explicit-semantic-analysis) ostensibly deals with a similar issue, though not really.

Comment: This is not really about programming. You may want to migrate that question to stats.

Comment: this is certainly about programming as it's about an algorithm and what is programming about if algorithms are not encompassed? moreover there is a precedent for asking such questions as the one I linked to which has over 600 views, demonstrating a communty interest in such inquireis

Comment: Note that many machine learning algorithms require a deep understanding of the statistical background - Yes, you are right, it's not completely off-topic here. But believe me - for a good answer to this question you don't need a good programmer, you need someone who is good at statistics. :)

Comment: that's true, but they're not disjoint sets. what site did you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between Latent Semantic Analysis and so-called Explicit Semantic Analysis lies in the corpus that is used and in the dimensions of the vectors that model word meaning.

Latent Semantic Analysis starts from document-based word vectors, which capture the association between each word and the documents in which it appears, typically with a weighting function such as tf-idf. It then reduces the dimensionality of these word vectors to (generally) 300, using Singular Value Decomposition. In contrast to the original dimensions (which corresponded to the documents), these 300 new dimensions have no straightforward interpretation. They are therefore called "latent". LSA can then be used to classify texts by combining all the vectors of the words in a text.

From the paper you mention, I understand Explicit Semantic Analysis is a document-based model as well: it models words in terms of the Wikipedia articles in which they appear. It differs from Latent Semantic Analysis, however, in that (a) the corpus (Wikipedia) cannot be chosen freely and (b) there is no dimensionality reduction involved. Again, the vectors of the words in a text can be combined to classify or otherwise interpret a text.

Comment: according to my understanding: in a traditional bag of word model there would be a kind of global dictionary and texts would be evaluated on the basis of their ability to populate that global dictionary, on in this way there are many concepts, each of which has it's own "global dictionary" of sorts and texts are evaluated against each of them to determine which Wikipedia "concept" they most resemble, is that your understanding too?
    
_________________________________________________________        is anything I said in the above paragraph, the grey one from the OP, is any of the innacurate?

Comment: Your comment and the paragraph in grey are correct. I should add that in LSA, too, you have "concepts" (the 300 dimensions in the reduced matrix) with their own "dictionary", but these concepts are less easily interpretable than the Wikipedia concepts.

Answer (score 1):

A simple explanation would be:

ESA - uses the knowledge-base like (wikipedia) to create inverted index that maps words to contents (i.e. title of a wikipedia page the word occurs in). Then operates over this vector representation of words, where each word is now a vector of titles with 0, 1 in them.

LSA - uses Singular Value Decomposition principle to project the word-doc matrix into a lower ranked space such that dot product of word-doc vector representation of words that do not co-occur with each other in any document, but they co-occur with a similar set of words (i.e. Imagine Cat and Car never co-occur in a document, but Can occurs with Man in some document D_1, and Car co-occurs with Man in some other document D_2) be higher.